# counting upvotes and downvotes

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table like this:

```
id  cid     u_id  vote  user_ip     date_added 
--------------------------------------------------------------
67  188     13      0   127.0.0.1   1356686070
68  188     15      1   127.0.0.1   1356686765
69  291     13      1   127.0.0.1   1356688859
70  62      15      1   127.0.0.1   1356695284
71  370     23      1   127.0.0.1   1356892215
73  232     23      1   127.0.0.1   1356893261
74  152     23      1   127.0.0.1   1356893591
76  75      15      1   127.0.0.1   1356924002
77  201     15      1   127.0.0.1   1356927284
```

In the `vote` column, `0` represents a downvote, and `1` represents an upvote. How would I go about calculating the downvotes and upvotes for each `cid`?

The result would be something like this:

```
cid   upvotes  downvotes
188   1        1
291   1        0
291   1        0
```

Comment: Can't fathom properly what is being asked, can you just edit and be more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT cid,
  SUM(vote) AS upvoted,
  SUM(CASE
        WHEN vote = 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) AS downvoted
FROM yourtablename
GROUP BY cid;
```